Transfer data from PLC to PC through ethernet
like the title, I'm trying to use the SEND(090) function to send a signal from an omron cp2E PLC to the computer via ethernet. But I tried many times but couldn't install it. I know you can use polling to continuously read a DM memory cell to see if it changes, but that will affect software performance. Can anyone who has ever sent signals from a PLC to a PC help me? Thank you very much everyone.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Check that you’ve defined the SEND(090) message correctly using CX-Programmer. Double-check your configuration to make sure you’ve set up the SEND(090) message properly. You should verify that the Ethernet cable is securely connected between the PLC and your PC. Try to ping the device to see if the issue is a connection or software issue.
Navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\OMRON\Communications Middleware and launch DirectEthernetUtility.
Select the correct network card (if you have multiple) and check the IP address2.
You could also consider using Ethernet Send/Receive Data Function Blocks. These blocks are designed to exchange data between CP2E-N-type CPU Units using the built-in Ethernet ports. They simplify data exchange without complex programming
